# Delay between each request

Tags: javascript, php

I have this Index.php wants to work as needed to execute each request at each defined time:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
textarea:hover, input:hover, textarea:active, input:active, textarea:focus, input:focus {
        outline:0px !important;
    }
button:focus {outline:0;}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: black; 
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue; 
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: blue; 
}

</style>
<title>ADFocus</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="cor">
<div><h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<textarea id="lista" name="lista" rows="5" required="" cols="1" style="overflow:auto; width:50%; height:50%; text-align: center;" cols="1"  placeholder=""></textarea>
<br>
<font color="black">
Aprovadas : <span id="cLive" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">0</span> - 
Reprovadas : <span id="cDie" class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">0</span> - 
Testadas: <span id="total" class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">0</span> - 
Total : <span id="carregadas" class="badge badge-pill badge-info">0</span></font>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="width: 500px; outline: none;"id="testar" onclick="enviar()">TESTAR</button>
<hr>


<span class="aprovadas" id=".aprovadas"></span>


<span class="reprovadas" id=".reprovadas"></span>



</center>

</body>

<script title="ajax do checker">
    function enviar() {
        var linha = $("#lista").val();
        var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
        var total = linhaenviar.length;
        var ap = 0;
        var rp = 0;
        linhaenviar.forEach(function(value, index) {
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'api.php?lista=' + value,
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: true,
                        success: function(resultado) {
                            if (resultado.match("#Aprovada")) {
                                removelinha();
                                ap++;
                                aprovadas(resultado + "");
                            }else {
                                removelinha();
                                rp++;
                                reprovadas(resultado + "");
                            }
                            $('#carregadas').html(total);
                            var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                            $('#cLive').html(ap);
                            $('#cDie').html(rp);
                            $('#total').html(fila);
                        }
                    });
                }, 3000 * index);
        });
    }
    function aprovadas(str) {
        $(".aprovadas").append(str + "<br>");
    }
    function reprovadas(str) {
        $(".reprovadas").append(str + "<br>");
    }
    function removelinha() {
        var lines = $("#lista").val().split('\n');
        lines.splice(0, 1);
        $("#lista").val(lines.join("\n"));
    }
</script>
```

He pauses between each test as I want.

**However I needed that same Pause but with this HTML.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--get out, you will not copy my html-->
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Checker GG</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/vendor/animate.css/animate.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/pe-icons/pe-icon-7-stroke.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/pe-icons/helper.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/stroke-icons/style.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
  <!--my own css-->
  <style>
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;

  }
  #top-bar{
      background-color: #3E3D3D;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    
    background-color: #;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
  }
  #title-top-bar{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    left: 55px;
  }
  #logo-top-bar{
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
  }
  #shop-redirect-mold{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #202a38;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
  }
  #shop-redirect-mold2{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -195px;
  }
  #db-list-box{
    background-color: #212a36;
    width: 70%;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
  }
  #lista{
    background-color:#2e;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #686868;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
#botao{
    background-color:#2e;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #686868;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
  #db-list-title{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #db-list-result-cont{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #result-box{
    position: relative;
    left: 205px;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: #212a36;
    width: 800px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #lives{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #28a745;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #dies{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #dc3545;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #socks{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffc107;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #1a222e;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
}
 </style>
    <!--website content-->
    <body class="animated bounce">
      <!--top bar and navegation-->


     <!--first text box-->
     


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-S7YMK1xjUjSpEnF4P8hPUcgjXYLZKK3fQW1j5ObLSl787II9p8RO9XUGehRmKsxd" crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
 

</head>
<body>

            
  <center> <br>
  <h1  style="font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; font-size: 30px;"> Checker GG ELO2</h1>
 

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>


    <center>
        <textarea id="list" name="lista" rows="5" required="" cols="1" style="overflow:auto; width:50%; height:50%; text-align: center;" cols="1"  placeholder="" maxlength="670"></textarea>


        <textarea name="socks" id="socks" rows="9" class="form-control" style="width:1%;text-align:left;resize:none;margin-left:-10140px;margin-top:-193px;" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Status: </span> <span class="badge badge-custom" id="status">Aguardando...</span>
                                           <br> <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Carregadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="total">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Aprovados: </span>  <span class="badge badge-success" id="live">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Reprovadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-danger" id="die">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Testadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-warning" id="testadas">0</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  <br>
                                  <br>
                                  </center>
        
<div class="button-list">
   <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="start">INICIAR</i></button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="stop">PARAR</button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="clear">LIMPAR</button>
</div>
<script>
        var audio = new Audio('blop.mp3');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#status').html('<span id="bad" class="badge badge-danger">Não iniciado !</span>');
                $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#start').click(function () {
                    audio.play();
                    var line = $('#list').val().split('\n');
                    var total = line.length;
                    var ap = 0;
                    var rp = 0;
                    var sd = 0;
                    $('#total').html(total);
                    line.forEach(function (value) {
                        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                            url: 'api.php',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: 'lista=' + value,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-success">Testando !</span>');
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#start').attr('disabled','disabled');
                            },

            success: function(data){
                if(data.indexOf("Aprovada") >= 0){
                    $("#aprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#aprovadas").val());
                    ap = ap + 1;
                    document.getElementById("aprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    audio.play();
                    removelinha();
                }else{
                    $("#reprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#reprovadas").val());
                    rp = rp + 1;
                    document.getElementById("reprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    removelinha();
                }
                    var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                    $('#live').html(ap);
                    $('#die').html(rp);
                    $('#testadas').html(fila);
                    if (fila == total) {
                        $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                        $('#stop').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
                        $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-info">Teste Finalizado !</span>');
                        audio.play();
                    }
                }
            });
             $('#stop').click(function(){
            ajaxCall.abort();
            $('#start').attr('disabled',null);
            $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
          });
        });
        $('#stop').click(function(){
          $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Parado !</span>');
          
        });
        
        $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-secondary">Lista Limpa!</span>');
                $('#list').val('');
            });
            });
        });
        function removelinha() {
            var lines = $("#list").val().split('\n');
                lines.splice(50, 50);
                $("#list").val(lines.join("\n"));
            }

        </script>

        </div>
    </center>
    <center><br>
           <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-content">
       <div style="text-align: center;" class="panel-heading"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i><strong> APROVADAS </strong><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
       <div style="font-size: 15px;" class="aprovados">
        <div id="aprovadas" class="card-body"></div>
       
   </div>
   </div>   
    
   <div class="panel panel-content">
       <div style="text-align: center;" class="panel-heading"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> REPROVADA <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div>
       <div style="font-size: 15px;" class="reprovadas">
       <div  id="reprovadas" class="card-body"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </center> 
    
    </html>
```

I'm running on LocalHost I have no problem with HTML, my question how to put this Pause as in the First in the Example.

Comment: You HTML is not valid. Please first go to w3org and check your HTML. Do not use the deprecated center tag and have only ONE body. ALL links need to be HTTPS and only have ONE of each of bootstrap and jQuery
Also your Script is not complete. Click edit, then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] with RELEVANT HTML and JS

Comment: ALL your timeouts run at 2000 milliseconds. That do not sit there and wait for it to run before the next one. You need to bump them up by 2000 each time.

Comment: I give up trying to fix this. You are playing on click AND you try to loop and play. Have ONE play function and ONE ajax function. You likely want to play the next song when the first is finished so you do NOT want setTimeout but use event handlers on the audio element

Comment: Sorry, I will edit to ask

Comment: You also need to delegate, then you can remove all the junk you have duplicated inside the ajax beforesend

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any setTimeout in this case; You need to use [Promises, async/await](https://javascript.info/async) in JavaScript; when you send a request to API, it will wait until you get a response from it.